# What is wrong about my proof?

Tags: real-analysis

The excersise: prove or disprove: if $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly, and $f(x)$ is continous, then $f_n(x)$ is continous for all $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$.

My proof:
Let $\varepsilon>0$. From the definition of continuity if $|x-a|<\delta$: $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon/3$.
Because $f_n\to f$ uniformly, there exists an $N$ such that, for all $x$ in the domain: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon/3$.
Then, for all $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<\delta$
, and for all $n>N$:
$|f_n(x)-f_n(a)|\le|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f_n(a)|<\varepsilon/3+\varepsilon/3+\varepsilon/3=\varepsilon$.

This proof seems correct to me but if we take $D(x)/n$ where $D(x)$ is Dirichlet's function you can see that it is wrong.

Comment: *"Let $\varepsilon>0$. From the definition of continuity if $|x-a|<\delta$: $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon/3$."* This sentence is missing something. You introduced $\varepsilon$, but not $\delta$ and $a$. What is $\delta$? What is $a$?

Comment: Consider $f_n(x)=\frac{\operatorname{sign}(x)}{n}$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You did not prove the statement since you have not define $n_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. So there is no fixed $N$ such that $f_n$ is continuous for $n>N$.

$f_n=\frac f n$ with $f$ bounded and dis-continuous gives  a counter-example to what you are trying to prove.

Comment: How is iN dependent on a?

Comment: @איתןכחלון $N$ should not depend on $\epsilon$

Comment: How does N depend on epsilon?

Comment: It does, obviously. Read your  sentence where you apply uniform convergence. @איתןכחלון

Comment: Thank you so much, if i understand correctly, if we want |f_n-f_n(a)| to be smaller than epsilon, we will have to choose a different N for smaller epsilons, and then there isn't a fixed N which for f_n will be less than epsilon for *all*epsilon

Comment: @איתןכחלון That is right.